# How to concat a string in oracle query in shell script

Tags: oracle, unix

Im trying to run below script and its not working.

```
datafile_name="/u02/oraarch/test300.dbf"
FINAL=1
sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" <<END
alter database datafile '$datafile_name' resize '$FINAL'M;
END


expected output:-
alter database datafile '/u02/oraarch/test300.dbf' resize 10M;
```

Answer (score 2):

A size value cannot have a string in it.

The `'$FINAL'M` character sequence contains ticks; for this reason, it will be treated as a string and not as a size value.

```
'$FINAL'M;
```

Instead you need something like this:

```
rm /tmp/resize.sql
export datafile_name="/u02/oraarch/test300.dbf"
export size="300M"
echo "alter database datafile '$datafile_name' resize $size;" > /tmp/resize.sql
echo "quit" >> /tmp/resize.sql
sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" @/tmp/resize.sql
```

You can also try this in your existing script - but do not put ticks in the size value:

```
alter database datafile '$datafile_name' resize ${FINAL}M;
```